Why login key is not being set inside PHP super global variable $_POST?
I am trying to understand how $_POST variable is being set when sending form data. I have understood for any variable to set inside $_POST, I must use the method post and all the form elements must have name attribute set. This is working with other input type but not with input type submit.
Frontend code.
<form method="POST">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />

    <input type="submit" value="login" name="login"/>
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the form from actually submitting
    console.log("catching event")
    // Create a FormData object from the form
    const formData = new FormData(this);

    // Optionally, you can send the form data using fetch
    fetch('login.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData  // Send the FormData object
    })
    .then(response => response.text())  // Assume server responds with text
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Server Response:', data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
</script>


Server Side code :
<?php
echo $_POST["username"].",";
echo $_POST['password'].",";
echo $_POST['login'];
?>

I am getting below output.


As per the MDN docs -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#submitter, form data if the submitter has the attribute  name.

Sure. But you didn't do that in your code. You only supplied the form itself. The submitter is an option you have to pass to the constructor yourself.

Like this formData.append("lol","cats")

Well, you could do it using append, but it was kinda missing the point I think. The submitter approach is newer and perhaps a bit neater. The duplicate question I linked you to shows both ways in different answers. Here's a demo using the  submitter argument in the FormData constructor, as per the documentation you yourself provided! https://jsfiddle.net/m6cnskug/
